# How to substitute NULL values using LAG window function when table is updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql, lag

I have a SQL database and I store data from vehicles in a table. Among these data, I store the electric consumption of every trip in a column and in another column I calculate the difference of this consumption between rows, using the LAG() function.

This LAG() function always sets to NULL the first row (if you have 10 values, there are 9 difference values), it's logical.

When I get the difference, I store the date of last update, so the next time I update the table, the process starts from this stored date and so. My problem is when I update the table with new consumption values, there's always one new NULL value in the difference column.

This is my code, works fine but I need to get the previous stored value and do the calculation to avoid null values:

```
    DECLARE
  schemaName TEXT;
  tableName TEXT;
  text_var1 TEXT;
  text_var2 TEXT;
  text_var3 TEXT;
  consulta TEXT;
  tablaJoinConsumos TEXT;
  tablaJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  tablaExtraJoinConsumos TEXT;
  tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  tmpDifCon TEXT;
  tmpDifConEco TEXT;
  tmpDifRec TEXT;
  tmpDifRecEco TEXT;
  dropTablaJoinConsumos TEXT;
  dropTablaJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  dropTablaExtraJoinConsumos TEXT;
  dropTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  dropTmpDifCon TEXT;
  dropTmpDifRec TEXT;
  creoTablaJoinConsumos TEXT;
  creoTablaJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  creoTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  creoTablaExtraJoinConsumos TEXT;
  creoTmpDifCon TEXT;
  creoTmpDifRec TEXT;
  selectLastEnergiasVehicleData TEXT;
  selectExtraJoinConsumos TEXT;
  selectExtraJoinRecuperadas TEXT;
  selectEcon TEXT;
  selectErec TEXT;
  updateVehicleDataCon TEXT;
  updateVehicleDataRec TEXT;
  registros RECORD;
  energias RECORD;
  ultimaFecha RECORD;
  vehicleData RECORD;
  diferencias RECORD;
  subtrips RECORD;

  col BOOLEAN;

 BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'ESTOY EN FNC_CALCENERGIAS()';
  --nombro esquema, tablas...
  schemaName = CONCAT($1, '_org');
  tableName = FORMAT('%s_%s_subtrip', $1, $2);
  tablaJoinConsumos = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_join_consumida', $1, $2); --aqui guardo datos de energia consumida y consumida modo eco para despues calcular diferencias
  tablaExtraJoinConsumos = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_extra_join_con', $1, $2);
  tablaJoinRecuperadas = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_join_recuperada', $1, $2);
  tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_extra_join_rec', $1, $2);

  tmpDifCon = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_difcon', $1, $2);
  tmpDifRec = FORMAT('tmp_%s_%s_difrec', $1, $2);

  --creo columnas de diferencias
  RAISE NOTICE 'VOY A CREAR COLUMNAS DE DIFERENCIAS, SI NO EXISTEN';
  col = TRUE;
  EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT FALSE FROM pg_attribute WHERE  attrelid = ''%I.%I''::regclass AND attname = ''dif_energiacon'' AND NOT attisdropped AND attnum > 0',
    schemaName, tableName) INTO col;
  IF col IS NULL OR col THEN
    -- Poner las columnas que faltan
    EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I.%I
      ADD COLUMN dif_energiacon real DEFAULT 0,
      ADD COLUMN dif_energiaconeco real DEFAULT 0,
    ADD COLUMN dif_energiarec real DEFAULT 0,
      ADD COLUMN dif_energiarececo real DEFAULT 0',
      schemaName, tableName);
  END IF;

  RAISE NOTICE 'HE CREADO COLUMNAS DE DIFERENCIAS, SI NO EXISTÍAN';

  --SELECTS
  consulta := FORMAT('SELECT tripid, halt, seq, energiacon, energiarec, energiaconeco, energiarececo FROM %I.%I WHERE seq > 0 AND orgid = %s AND vehicleid = %s ORDER BY halt;', schemaName, tableName, $1, $2);

  dropTablaJoinConsumos := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tablaJoinConsumos);
  dropTablaJoinRecuperadas := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tablaJoinRecuperadas);
  dropTablaExtraJoinConsumos := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tablaExtraJoinConsumos);
  dropTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas);
  dropTmpDifCon := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tmpDifCon);
  dropTmpDifRec := FORMAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I;', tmpDifRec);

  creoTablaJoinConsumos := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, consumo real, dif_consumos real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq, consumo));', tablaJoinConsumos);
  creoTablaExtraJoinConsumos := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, dif_consumo real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq));', tablaExtraJoinConsumos);
  creoTablaJoinRecuperadas := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, recuperada real, dif_consumos real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq, recuperada));', tablaJoinRecuperadas);
  creoTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, dif_recuperada real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq));', tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas);
  creoTmpDifCon := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, dif_con real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq))', tmpDifCon);
  creoTmpDifRec := FORMAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (halt timestamptz, tripid integer, seq integer, dif_rec real, PRIMARY KEY(halt, tripid, seq))', tmpDifRec);


  selectExtraJoinConsumos := FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %I ORDER BY halt, seq;', tablaExtraJoinConsumos);
  selectExtraJoinRecuperadas := FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %I ORDER BY halt, seq;', tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas);

  selectEcon := FORMAT('SELECT tripid, halt, seq, energiacon FROM %I.%I WHERE seq > 0 AND energiacon > 0 ORDER BY halt, energiacon;', schemaName, tableName);
  selectErec := FORMAT('SELECT tripid, halt, seq, energiarec FROM %I.%I WHERE seq > 0 AND energiarec > 0 ORDER BY halt, energiarec', schemaName, tableName);


  selectLastEnergiasVehicleData := FORMAT('SELECT lastenergiacon, lastenergiarec FROM public.vehicle_data WHERE orgid = %s AND vehicleid = %s;', $1, $2);

  --UPDATES
  updateVehicleDataCon := FORMAT('UPDATE public.vehicle_data SET lastenergiacon = (SELECT halt FROM "tmp_%s_%s_difcon" ORDER BY halt DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE orgid = %s AND vehicleid = %s;', $1, $2, $1, $2);
  updateVehicleDataRec := FORMAT('UPDATE public.vehicle_data SET lastenergiarec = (SELECT halt FROM "tmp_%s_%s_difrec" ORDER BY halt DESC LIMIT 1) WHERE orgid = %s AND vehicleid = %s;', $1, $2, $1, $2);

  RAISE NOTICE 'DROPS';
  EXECUTE dropTablaJoinConsumos;
  EXECUTE dropTablaJoinRecuperadas;
  EXECUTE dropTablaExtraJoinConsumos;
  EXECUTE dropTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas;
  EXECUTE dropTmpDifCon;
  EXECUTE dropTmpDifRec;

  RAISE NOTICE ' CREATES';
  EXECUTE creoTablaJoinConsumos;
  EXECUTE creoTablaExtraJoinConsumos;
  EXECUTE creoTablaJoinRecuperadas;
  EXECUTE creoTablaExtraJoinRecuperadas;
  EXECUTE creoTmpDifCon;
  EXECUTE creoTmpDifRec;

FOR ultimaFecha IN EXECUTE selectLastEnergiasVehicleData LOOP
RAISE NOTICE ' 122';
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--fechas son NULL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I.%I set (lastenergiacon, lastenergiarec) VALUES = (0, 0);', schemaName, tableName);
--CASE 1 -> compruebo energias consumidas
RAISE NOTICE ' 128';
  CASE
    WHEN ultimaFecha.lastenergiacon IS NULL THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'CASE 1.1 - LASTENERGIACON ES NULL';
      FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectEcon LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, consumo) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tablaJoinConsumos, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.energiacon);
      END LOOP;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_consumo) SELECT halt, tripid, seq, consumo - LAG(consumo) OVER (ORDER BY consumo) AS dif_consumo FROM %I;', tablaExtraJoinConsumos, tablaJoinConsumos);
       --datos de consumida y consumida en modo eco en la misma tabla

      FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectExtraJoinConsumos LOOP
              EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_con) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tmpDifCon, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.dif_consumo);
      END LOOP;

      EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I.%I AS a SET dif_energiacon=b.dif_con FROM (SELECT halt, dif_con FROM  %I) AS b WHERE a.halt=b.halt;', schemaName, tableName, tmpDifCon);
      EXECUTE updateVehicleDataCon;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      WHEN ultimaFecha.lastenergiacon IS NOT NULL THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'CASE 1.2 - LASTENERGIACON NO ES NULL';
        FOR registros IN EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT tripid, halt, seq, energiacon FROM %I.%I WHERE seq > 0 AND energiacon > 0 AND halt >= %L ORDER BY halt, energiacon;', schemaName, tableName, ultimaFecha.lastenergiacon) LOOP
          EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, consumo) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tablaJoinConsumos, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.energiacon);
        END LOOP;
        EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_consumo) SELECT halt, tripid, seq, consumo - LAG(consumo) OVER (ORDER BY consumo) AS dif_consumo FROM %I;', tablaExtraJoinConsumos, tablaJoinConsumos);
        --datos de consumida y consumida en modo eco en la misma tabla

        FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectExtraJoinConsumos LOOP
                EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_con) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tmpDifCon, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.dif_consumo);
        END LOOP;
        --actualizo tabla subtrip y vehicle_data
        EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I.%I AS a SET dif_energiacon=b.dif_con FROM (SELECT halt, dif_con FROM  %I) AS b WHERE a.halt=b.halt;', schemaName, tableName, tmpDifCon);
        EXECUTE updateVehicleDataCon;
  END CASE;

--CASE 2 -> compruebo energias recuperadas
    CASE
      WHEN ultimaFecha.lastenergiarec IS NULL THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'CASE 2.1 - LASTENERGIAREC ES NULL';
        FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectErec LOOP
          EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, recuperada) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tablaJoinRecuperadas, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.energiarec);
        END LOOP;
        EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_recuperada) SELECT halt, tripid, seq, recuperada - LAG(recuperada) OVER (ORDER BY recuperada) AS dif_recuperada FROM %I;', tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas, tablaJoinRecuperadas);
        --datos de energia recuperada y recuperada en modo eco en la misma tabla

        FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectExtraJoinRecuperadas LOOP
                EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_rec) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tmpDifRec, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.dif_recuperada);
        END LOOP;
        --actualizo tabla subtrip y vehicle_data

        EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I.%I AS a SET dif_energiarec=b.dif_rec FROM (SELECT halt, dif_rec FROM %I) AS b WHERE a.halt=b.halt;', schemaName, tableName, tmpDifRec);
        EXECUTE updateVehicleDataRec;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      WHEN ultimaFecha.lastenergiarec IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'CASE 2.3 - LASTENERGIAREC NO ES NULL';
        FOR registros IN EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT tripid, halt, seq, energiarec FROM %I.%I WHERE seq > 0 AND energiarec > 0 AND halt >= %L ORDER BY halt, energiarec', schemaName, tableName, ultimaFecha.lastenergiarec) LOOP
          EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, recuperada) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tablaJoinRecuperadas, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.energiarec);
        END LOOP;
        EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_recuperada) SELECT halt, tripid, seq, recuperada - LAG(recuperada) OVER (ORDER BY recuperada) AS dif_recuperada FROM %I;', tablaExtraJoinRecuperadas, tablaJoinRecuperadas);
        --datos de energia recuperada y recuperada en modo eco en la misma tabla

        FOR registros IN EXECUTE selectExtraJoinRecuperadas LOOP
                EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I (halt, tripid, seq, dif_rec) VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L);', tmpDifRec, registros.halt, registros.tripid, registros.seq, registros.dif_recuperada);
        END LOOP;
        --actualizo tabla subtrip y vehicle_data
        EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE %I.%I AS a SET dif_energiarec=b.dif_rec FROM (SELECT halt, dif_rec FROM  %I) AS b WHERE a.halt=b.halt;', schemaName, tableName, tmpDifRec);
        EXECUTE updateVehicleDataRec;
    END CASE;

END LOOP;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RETURN 1;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Gestion de excepciones
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                          text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                          text_var3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'fnc_calcEnergias: %', text_var1;
    RAISE NOTICE 'fnc_calcEnergias: %', text_var1;
    RAISE NOTICE 'fnc_calcEnergias: %', text_var1;
    RETURN 0;
  END;
```

The next image shows the problem, the 4th column is the electric consumption and the **5th column** is the difference between consumptions, what I'm trying to explain. (The same happens with the 6th and **7th** columns, that's the recovered energy).

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5URH.png)

How could be this done? One option could be update the entire without storing the date of last update, but I prefer to avoid this one, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL? (the problem could be demonstrated in plain SQL)

Comment: Yes there is, the lag() function is in the second 'EXECUTE FORMAT', just after the the first 'END LOOP'

Comment: I use dynamic sql because it's more comfortable to write, you can write shorter sentences...but I think this is not important. (I'm a noob in SQL, maybe I'm wrong). The problem is how could I get the last consumption value everytime I update the table and substitute those NULL values with the proper difference...since you can't nest window functions

Comment: @David You're right that it doesn't change the overall question, but it makes it harder to read and those loops don't make any sense since you aren't changing the table or column inside the loop.  Overall, it would be much easier to answer this question if we had a pared-down version of your table structure, some sample data, and an expected output.

Comment: Postgres version and table definition are minimum requirements. When showing dynamic SQL, show the complete function (or procedure or `DO` statement). But dynamic SQL only obfuscates the core of this question. Present a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Comment: You are right, so I added the complete code of my function.
What I'm trying to do now (is not in this code, because I'm already testing it) is to duplicate the last row I used for the las calculation so I'd have an extra duplicate row but with all the differences calculated, BUT I can't because of the primary keys. I think a valid solution could be doing this but with a temporary table and then updating the original table.